# Failed to restart idmapd.service: Unit idmapd.service is masked

Tags: networking, server, 16.04

I tried running `systemctl unmask idmapd` and then `service idmapd restart`, but it still gives me the same error.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit and my server is also Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

When I check if it's running, I get this:

```
service idmapd status
● idmapd.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

And for the other one:

```
$ service nfs-idmapd status 
● nfs-idmapd.service - NFSv4 ID-name mapping service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-idmapd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
$ service nfs-idmapd start 
Failed to start nfs-idmapd.service: Unit nfs-server.service not found.
```

Comment: Is nfs-idmapd the same as idmapd? The idmapd.service file is installed as /dev/null however, rpc.idmapd should be running if nfs-idmapd is loaded, active, and running.

Comment: Good question, @mchid.  I tired (re)starting the nfs-idmapd service and got this error "Failed to start nfs-idmapd.service: Unit nfs-server.service not found".  Same for rpc.idpapd.

Comment: Looks like I may need to reinstall the server completely and start fresh.

Comment: Do you have installed nfs-kernel-server package on server and client? On my 18.04 client, I need this package on the client too to get the nfs-idmapd.service running. Seems to be a bug, because I need a server package on a client to get a NFS mount with nfsv4???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like your nfs-server package has problems

```
Failed to start nfs-idmapd.service: Unit nfs-server.service not found.
```

suggests that either the nfs-server.service file is missing or its in the wrong place. You could try to start it manually to test this theory

```
systemctl nfs-server start
```

have a look for it in /etc/systemd/ to see if you cant find it, it you are lucky its just in the wrong target folder

```
find /etc/systemd/ -name nfs-server.service
```

Comment: Got this: `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nfs-server.service
`.

Comment: so you have a script to start it , what happens if you run the systemctl command to start it ?

Comment: I don't have one, I have a freshly installed Ubuntu Server with the basic set up for NFS.

Comment: i think you need to apt-get install either the  nfs-kernel-server or nfs-server package

Comment: I have those installed.

Comment: for what ever reason nfs-server.service appears to be in the wrong place or your nfs-server.service file is corrupt.   journalctl nfs-service or nfs-idmapd should give you some logs that explain the issue more.

Comment: "-- No entries --"  for both services.

Comment: @SvetlanaBelkin Can you please explain further what you mean by "No entries", thanks. `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nfs-server.service` should be a sim link to the actual file which is `/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service` You can run `file $(find /etc/systemd/ -name nfs-server.service)` to confirm this.

Comment: no entries means there where no logs so those services have never started

Comment: @mchid I ran the command and did get, "/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nfs-server.servi‌​ce" but don't know how to check if the sim link goes to the correct file.

Comment: stat /path/to/symlink

Answer (score 4):

You need to use sudo to unmask and mask services.

The command:

```
sudo systemctl unmask idmapd
```

should do the trick. Then:

```
sudo service idmapd start
```

or

```
sudo service idmapd restart
```

**UPDATE**

I believe `nfs-idmapd` replaces this service. You will need the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

If that doesn't work, purge the offending packages and then reinstall them.

```
sudo apt-get purge nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
sudo apt-get install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error because it still asks for my password both ways.

Comment: @SvetlanaBelkin `sudo` commands always require a password.

Comment: Read my comment.

Comment: I tried the updated part and still same error.